# Need help understanding the [Same birthday as you] birthday problem

Tags: probability

I need help understanding "Same birthday as you" [similar to the original birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Same_birthday_as_you).

There are ${23 \choose 2} = 253$ ways of finding a pair in 23 people.

The probability of any two people having the same birthday as myself (e.g. *Aug 30*) is $\frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365}$

The probability of existing one pair in 23 people having the same birthday as myself is:
$(\frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365}) + \dots + (\frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365}) = 253 \times \frac{1}{365} \times \frac{1}{365} = 0.00189904297
$

This Wikipedia question:

> [image]

Comment: Birthday problem is finding a pair who have a common birthday, not the same birthday as you.

Comment: @QED this is the "Same birthday as you" variation

Comment: The "same birthday as you" variant is looking at the probability that at least one other person in the group has the same birthday as you. It is *not* about trying to find a pair of people who share your birthday.

Comment: @ConMan do you mean I should consider the group as 24 people instead?

Comment: It's better to think of it as the probability that in a group of 23 people, *none* of them have a birthday of August 30th.

Comment: What you actually calculated is not a *probability* but is the *expectation* of the number of pairs among $23$ persons that consist out of $2$ persons having the same birthday date as you have. To see clear that it is not a probability do the same thing for some $n$ persons where $n$ satisfies $\binom{n}2>365^2$. It gives you a value that exceeds $1$ hence is not a probability.